# Deallocate memory previously allocated to a variable (using create)

Tags: memory-management, forth, gforth

I'm reading the [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth) manual on memory allocation / deallocation, and this is something I cannot understand. Suppose I allocated a chunk of memory to hold four integers like this:

```
create foo 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,
```

Then, maybe I allocated more memory and perhaps deallocated some too, and now I want to deallocate `foo`. How do I do that? Doing `foo free` and `foo 4 cells free` results in an error.

Comment: LOL, @PeterMortensen , I bet of 115 people subscribed to `forth` tag there isn't one, who can't find Gforth manual... Replacing 4 with "four", come on... there was absolutely no need in your edit, please stop following my posts! This stalker-ish behaviour is weird and absolutely uncalled for.

Comment: @user797257, maybe Peter has the 116th person in mind?  In any case, I really appreciate his edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `forget foo` but that will 'deallocate' everything that you have defined since you defined `foo`, and worse than that Gforth doesn't implement it. In Gforth you have to use a 'marker', but this also will revert everything that happened after the marker.

For example (I'll show what you would get entering this into a Gforth interpreter, including the interpreter's responses (denoted by double asterisks)):

```
marker -unfoo **ok**

create foo 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , **ok**

/ A test word to get the first thing in foo (1) back
: test foo @ . ; **ok**

test **1 ok** 

-unfoo **ok**

foo

**:8: Undefined word
>>>foo<<<
Backtrace:
$7FAA4EB4 throw
$7FAB1628 no.extensions
$7FAA502C interpreter-notfound1**

test

**:8: Undefined word
>>>test<<<
Backtrace:
$7FAA4EB4 throw
$7FAB1628 no.extensions
$7FAA502C interpreter-notfound1**
```

The example is meant to illustrate that `foo` and `test` are both gone after you execute `-unfoo`.

How this actually works is probably my moving the address that the interpreter is taking as the last thing added to the dictionary. `-unfoo` moves this back to before the address at which `foo` was added, which is equivalent to freeing the memory used by `foo`.

Here is another reference for this [Starting Forth](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/sf3/sf3.html) which is pretty excellent for picking up Forth in general.

---

In response to a comment on this answer:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882326/memory-management-in-forth) is quite similar and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609133) is pretty helpful. [This](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Heap-Allocation.html) is probably the most relevant part of the Gforth documentation.

The links above explain Forth versions of `malloc()`, `free()` and `resize()`.

So in answer to your original question, you can use `free` but the memory that you free has to have been allocated by `allocate` or `resize`.

`create` adds an item to the dictionary and is as such not exactly what you want if you are going to want the memory back. My understanding of this, which may be incorrect is that you wouldn't normally remove things from the dictionary during the course of normal execution.

The best way to store a string depends on what you want to do with it. If you don't need it to exist for the lifetime of the programme you can just use `s"` by itself as this returns a length and an address.

In general, I would say that using `create` is quite a good idea but it does have limitations. If the string changes you will have to `create` a new dictionary entry for it. If you can set an upper bound on the string length, then once you have `create`d a word you can go back and overwrite the memory that has been `allot`ed for it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748192/547299) is another answer that I gave that gives an example of defining a string word.

So in summary, if you really do need to be able to deallocate the memory, use heap methods that Gforth provides (I think that they are in the Forth standard but I don't know if all Forths implement them). If you don't you can use the dictionary as per your question.

Comment: Oh my... does this mean I will have to write my own allocator? Maybe I just don't ask the correct question. All I wanted is something like `alloc` / `free` pair. I also got an impression that this is how GForth allocates / deallocates memory. Is `create` in some way an analogue to static allocation? I.e. would you normally allocate / deallocate such entities in a program, or is this something unusual to do? All I wanted, technically, is to have a place, where to save a string of variable size (the string being allocated on the heap).

Comment: @wvxvw I have added some stuff to the end of my answer, that I hope addresses your comment.

Comment: Thank you! I'll need to dwell on that example a bit, but I think that it's steering me in the right direction. Also thank you for the extended explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE ALLOT and VARIABLE words consume dictionary space (look it up in the ISO 93 standard.)
Traditionally you can

> FORGET aap

, but that removes *aap* and each definition that is defined later than *aap* , totally different from free().

In complicated Forth's like gforth this simple mechanism no longer works. It amounted to truncating the linked list and resetting an allocation pointer (HERE/DP)

In gforth you are obliged to use MARKER. In putting

> ```
> MARKER aap
> ```

you can use *aap* to remove *aap* and later defined words.
*MARKER* is cumbersome and it is much easier to restart your Forth.